# Investigation of function with parameters

Tags: functions

I'm not so sure how to find the parameters "a" and "b" of this function, and ill be happy if someone could help me:

$$y=\frac{ax+bx+1}{x^2-6x-8}$$

The slope of the tangent function is:   $-\frac{40}{9}$ in the point $(5 , 5 \frac13)$

What will be the best way to find the parameters "a" and "b"?

Comment: I assume that it should be $ax^2$ in the numerator?  You have a point satisfying the equality, that gives you one equation.  Differentiate and set $x=5$ to find another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a function $f(x)=y$.

1. Because the graph of the function has a tangent in the point $(5, 5\frac13)$, you know that $$f(5)=5\frac13$$
2. Because the slope of the tangent is $-\frac{40}9$, you know that $$f'(5)=-\frac{40}9$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, a=1, b=-2 and btw im new to this forum so I wonder how do you learn to write all those math simbols like the "f" and the 1/3 and f'? now I use latex editor but its not so fast

Comment: @LiziPizi For short fixes, just try to edit your question and see how it's done there. For other uses: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference